# I keep receiving this error although I have followed a template for this code. Can anyone with experience spot something I cannot? I am new to R

Tags: r, object

**Error Message Error in ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = Row_Labels_1, y = Par_Count_1,:object 'my_data' not found**

and also

**Error in data.frame(responses, par_count) : object 'responses' not found**

```
data_setReading <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Survey_Data1_ENG.xlsx")

my_data <- data.frame(responses, par_count)

ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = responses, y = Par_Count_1, fill = responses)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(mapping = aes(label=Par_Count_1), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), cex = 2.5, vjust=-1) +    
  labs(fill = "Responses",
               x = "Youth Responses",
               y = "Youth Count",
               subtitle = "I want to come OR return to _ in person.",
               caption = "N = 273, youth responses to survey in English") +
               scale_fill_manual(values = c("Agree" = "#FCD81F",
                                            "Disagree" = "#F6A223",
                                            "Somewhat Agree" = "#EF801E",
                                            "Somewhat Disagree" = "#E75820")) + 
   theme_bw()
```

Comment: As the second error message is telling you there is no object called `responses`. Hence, setting up the data.frame fails and hence there is no data.frame `my_data` which results in the first error message. So the question is: What is `responses` and where does it come from? Have you created it or is it perhaps a column of the your dataset `data_setReading`?

Comment: I am importing an excel sheet that has a column labeled "responses" which I am trying to call for.

Comment: In that case you have to tell R that you mean the column of dataset `data_setReading`. I guess the same is true for `par_count`? In that case try with `my_data <- data_setReading[, c("responses", "par_count")]`. Additionally in your plotting code you use `Par_Count_1` which probably should be `par_count`.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that I was not specifying the columns!